# Accessing Service data in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-services

My code is coffeescript.
I have a singleton service for sharing the Session data between controllers:

```
angular.module('cargo').service 'Session', ->
  this.create = (attributes) ->
    this.user = attributes
  return
```

I'm creating a login system:

```
angular.module('cargo').factory 'AuthService', ($location, $resource, Session) ->
  authService = {}

  authService.login = (credentials) ->
    sessionResource = $resource('/api/sessions/:id')
    session = sessionResource.save user: {email: "example@example.com", password: "12345678"}, ->
      Session.create(session.user)

  authService.isAuthenticated = () ->
    !!Session.user.id

  authService
```

The problem is that when I access to Session.user.id (in authService.isAuthenticated) is null.
I tried to prompt the data with console.log(Session) and then I can see that the data is there. It has user with an attribute id. But if I try to prompt Session.user is already null.

Is there any way for accessing the data that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with coffeescript but in JS usually I use $http.post to do the auth like:

```
$http.post( my_url, { email: loginEmail, password: loginPassword } );
```

In the success callback I get the access token, which I attach to the $rootScope.

Then inside a controller I can call my $resource (declared as a normal resource) with:

```
MyService.get( { token: $rootScope.token } );
```